# Reading strings from a text file and sending them to server concurrently

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a theory question about concurrent network programming. I'm am trying to create a client-side networking tool, and I need it to perform very quickly. The program will read a list of IP addresses from a text file and run some function on them. This function for example:

```
void conn(char *host, const char *port, char *test_string)
{
    struct addrinfo *res;  
    struct addrinfo hints;      
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));   
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;    
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    
    getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
    int s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (s == -1) error("failed to open socket");
    int c = connect(s, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    // send string from file
    // recv message
    freeaddrinfo(res);          
}
```

I want send requests to the server concurrently for better performance, but I don't understand how I should do this exactly. I've done research on multithreading with posix threads but I can't come up with something that actually seems to run asynchronously

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stringlist)) {
    if ((c = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL) 
        *c = '\0';
        strncpy(args.test, buf, 20);
        pthread_create(&threads, NULL, conn, &args);
        pthread_join(threads, &res);
    }
}
```

I realize that certainly doesn't increase performance in any way, and I've done further research but I'm starting to feel lost. I'm aware of using fcntl to make the socket nonblocking and asynchronous, as well as the select function for i/o multiplexing, but I'm not sure which method is right in this situation.

My question in a nutshell is: What is a good method for reading strings from a text file and sending concurrent requests containing the strings to a server. Is multithreading right for this situation?

Comment: When you call `pthread_join`, the program waits until the thread finishes. So the loop creates one thread, waits for it to finish, and then reads the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really run in parallel:

```
pthread_create(&threads, NULL, conn, &args);
pthread_join(threads, &res);
```

Here the thread is created to do the job but the main thread is waiting for it to finish. So there is just single thread running at the same time - either the main or the worker.

To do it in parallel, there are two options:

1. Create and launch thread for every line from the file, and put it into the list. At the end, wait for all the threads with `pthread_join()`. This may work for reasonable amount of input lines as there is limit of total threads/processes usually.
2. Create a thread pool and the queue of work items. The queue will follow common producer-consumer pattern where the main thread is producer and thread pool threads are consumers. The consumer thread will pick the worker item when it's added into the queue and process it.

The second approach is much better, it limits the maximum number of threads and it can also make the underlying resource reusable (the socket connection).

Java has pretty good abstraction for this, see [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

For C you don't have so many options probably, either you can implement it yourself. That's not so difficult - one mutex protecting the queue structure and condition announcing the availability of the item (and maybe another if you want to limit the producer too). Or you can look at [Thread Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) or [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) which may provide the thread pools, queues and stuff like that.

Comment: Being that the thread creation happens inside of the fgets loop, wouldn't that mean that each thread would still only process one file entry at a time since fgets blocks?

Comment: @user348678 : yes, with the first option. But still the threads will run in parallel. The args argument would have to be allocated dynamically in any case as the next fgets would overwrite the existing solution